# React Native Router Flux, navigating causes an Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-native-router-flux

Building another react native app but I'm running into a super frustrating problem, whenever I have experienced this it's because I've missed an export but I'm fairly sure that's not the case this time.

When navigating to a route using RN Router Flux – I receive the error: `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

If I set that view as initial, all is well.

My routes are as follow:

```
import React from "react";
import {Scene, Stack} from "react-native-router-flux";

import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import AboutComponent from "../components/About";

import DevelopmentsComponent from "../components/Developments.js";
import DevelopmentsContainer from '../../containers/Developments.js'

import DevelopmentComponent from "../components/Development.js";
import DevelopmentContainer from "../../containers/Development.js";

const Index = (
    <Stack key="root" navBar={Navbar}>
        <Scene key="siteplan" component={AboutComponent} title="Login"/>
        <Scene initial key="developments" component={DevelopmentsContainer} Layout={DevelopmentsComponent} />

        <Scene
            clone
            key="development"
            component={DevelopmentContainer}
            Layout={DevelopmentComponent}
        />
    </Stack>
);

export default Index;
```

And the 'component' in question:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

import {getDevelopments, handleDevelopmentSelected} from "../actions/developments";

let fetchDevelopments = () => {
    return this.props.getDevelopments()
};

class DevelopmentList extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        Layout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        developments: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        getDevelopments: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        handleDevelopmentSelected: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    render = () => {
        const {Layout, developments, handleDevelopmentSelected, developmentsForComparison} = this.props;

        return (<Layout
            developments={developments}
            selectedForComparison={developmentsForComparison}
            reFetch={() => fetchDevelopments()}
            selectForComparison={(development) => handleDevelopmentSelected(development)}
        />)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return ({
        developments: state.developments.developments || {},
        developmentsForComparison: state.developments.developmentsForComparison || []
    })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getDevelopments,
    handleDevelopmentSelected
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DevelopmentList);
```

Which renders the layout component, for arguments sake:

```
import React from "react";
import {Container, Content} from "native-base";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {Text} from "react-native";
import Header from "./Header";

class DevelopmentComponent extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        developments: PropTypes.array,
        selectForComparison: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        selectedForComparison: PropTypes.array
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    developments = this.props.developments;

    render() {
        if (!this.developments.length) return <Text>No Developments</Text>;
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content padder>
                    <Header
                        title="AVAILABILITY"
                    />
                    <Text>Hello</Text>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
;

export default DevelopmentComponent
```

Am I missing something painfully obvious? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You've imported twice in the first snippet, it should throw Duplicate Declaration first.

Comment: @PritishVaidya We have a developments component which lists all of them, then upon selection, a development is displayed. It looks like a duplicate declaration but they are different, promise :p

Comment: Ohh! i got it by carefully looking at it.